# Java: How to create "variable" fields with static parts?

Tags: java, string, variables, variable-assignment, assign

I have a lot of fields that depend on the value of one field, like so:

```
private String root;
private String rootHide = root+"&hide";
private String rootApple = root+".apple.me";
...
```

Problem is, `root` is only assigned a value inside methods (non static, if that matters):

```
public myMethod () {
    root = "myRoot";
    System.out.println(rootHide);
    System.out.println(rootApple);
}
```

At the point of assigning a value to `root`, `rootHide` and `rootApple` are already assigned (null + their literal part).

I want, when root is assigned, the variables to "reassign" (or the variables to pick up the new root reference) and therefore result in `"myRoot&hide"` and `"myRoot.apple.me"` respectively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

#### Use a method to set `root`

...and also set the other two fields in that method:

```
private void setRoot(String root) {
    this.root = root;
    rootHide = root+"&hide";
    rootApple = root+".apple.me";
}
```

You would always do `setRoot("myRoot");` rather than `root = "myRoot";`

#### Use a method to get the other two fields

...and compute their values in the method:

```
private String getRootHide() {
    return root + "&hide";
}

private String getRootApple() {
    return root + ".apple.me";
}
```

You would then delete the fields `rootHide` and `rootApple`, and always call `getRootHide()` and `getRootApple` rather than accessing `rootHide` and `rootApple`.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps create a method that updates all variables when called

```
static update(String root){
rootHide = root+"&hide";
rootHide = root+"&hide";
}
```

call the method everytime you update root, or include setting of root so that it only needs to be called without first setting root.